# Splitting the data frame by using the user input in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working on Drug Recommendation Project and got stuck at one point.

Initially what I wanted was, to split the main data into various subset dataframe for doing some more detailed analysis:

```
df_acne_top = df_acne[(df_acne['Rating']<5) & (df_acne['Company_Name'] == 'Sun Pharmaceutical Industries Ltd.')].reset_index(drop = True)
df_acne_top
```

And I got the result!

But now what I wanted to do is to generalize the code using the 'INPUT' parameter.

While splitting the data from the main data frame in python, I want that according to user input user should get the new data frame.

I want to replace 'Sun Pharmaceutical Industries Ltd.' name and 'Rating' with user input so that a generalized code can be created.

The code which I am trying for generalization is below:

```
Company_name = input('Enter the company name')
df_acne_top = df_acne[(df_acne['Rating']<5) & (df_acne['Company_Name'] == Company_name)].reset_index(drop = True)
df_acne_top
```

but this time I am not getting the results. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? what output are you getting and what should it be? You haven't changed your rating to a user input yet

Comment: also, what happens if the users inputs something that's not in the table/has a typo?

Comment: Actually, due to limited badges, I am not able to share the Output image..

Comment: you should copy and paste, and format as code to add to your quesiton. Screen shots of code and some outputs are frowned upon on SO

Comment: For the first code which I shared, I am getting the results .. like I want to split the main data frame and get the name of the drug having ratings more than 3 or less than 5 supplied by Sun Pharmaceutical Industry. But this is just for one company. I want to create the generalised code, where the user specifies the company name and rating of the drug which he/she wants and gets the drug name accordingly.

Comment: and when the user inputs something that's not in the table, then he/she will get 'Company not listed as return'

Comment: I get that. in your own code,  you have added the user input for company_name, you just need to repeat with a rating input.

Comment: yeah! got that... but when I run the code with user input and give it the company name I only get the blank dataset.. no entries are there.. so this is what happens as the end result..

Comment: Is the user input for company_name definitely correct, no typos and an exact match to the names in the table

Comment: yes.. it is correct, no typo, no exact match of names in the table

Comment: Please include a reproducible sample.